# how to add duplicate data in queue into an JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arr = [2,3,4];
```

when I push data into an array

```
arr.push(2);
```

then the result is this --- `[2, 3, 4, 2]

but I want that this result -------`[2, 2, 3, 4]

I want similar numbers to be together

in a simple way I am just want,

I have [3, 4, 2, 6] and I add 2 and I want [3, 4, 2, 2, 6] not [2, 2, 3, 4, 6]

help me?

Comment: Ya, I typed wrong.

Comment: So improve your question. This would really help us a lot and would avoid downvotes for you. `:)`

Comment: @Aditya So you want the array to be sorted after you push an element to it? If not please add some explanation of the logic behind your  desired result.

Comment: yes, I want same value insert in a queue.

Comment: @Aditya Do you mean you want to add elements to the front instead of the back?

Comment: no, let me explain...
here is my arrya --- var arr = [2,3,4];
if i add --- arr.push(3);

result is--[2, 3, 4, 3]

but i want this result----[2, 3, 3, 4]

Comment: Alright so you do want it sorted? I'm not sure what that has to do with a queue.

Comment: Or do you want all duplicate entries to be next to each other, but not necessarily sorted? There are just too many ways to interpret your example.

Comment: Yes, I want all duplicate entries to be next to each other. so help me.

Comment: @Aditya So if you have `[3, 4, 2, 6]` and you add 2, you want `[3, 4, 2, 2, 6]`, and not `[2, 2, 3, 4, 6]`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) methods

```js
var arr = [2,3,4];

arr.splice(arr.indexOf(2),0,2);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the index of same or greater value and insert at that index.

```js
function insert(value, array) {
    array.splice(array.findIndex(v => v >= value), 0, value);
    return array;
}

console.log(insert(2, [2, 3, 4]));
console.log(insert(5, [2, 6, 7]));
console.log(insert(1, [2, 6, 7]));
```

Answer (score -1):

replace **arr.push(2)** with **arr.unshift(2);**